# Are paramagnetic materials in theory weakly attracted to everything?

Tags: electromagnetism

> *"Paramagnetism is a form of magnetism whereby some materials are weakly attracted by an externally applied magnetic field".*

Broadly speaking, all atoms, and molecules, and matter, has an electromagnetic field. Does this imply that a paramagnetic material is weakly, and to a varying degree, attracted to everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Non-magnetic materials don't produce a *net* magnetic field, because the magnetism from their individual particles don't align to give substantial total fields, but rather cancel out on average.

But if 'to a varying degree' you're willing to consider ridiculously small attraction forces, then we should consider that this cancellation isn't always perfect. If you have $N$ magnetic particles that can each point up or down (and do so independently of each other, which is a key assumption that won't always hold), then you'll almost never have *exactly* $N/2$ pointing up and $N/2$ pointing down. On average you'll have an excess of $\sim\sqrt{N}$ particles pointing in one direction or the other, and so there will be a small net magnetic field. This effect becomes bigger for smaller numbers of particles, and is relevant in NMR spectroscopy (where it's called statistical polarization). Thus I suppose there would be a tiny attractive force to any nearby paramagnet.

I should add as a disclaimer that I'm not sure whether statistical polarization would be the dominant contribution in a realistic scenario, but it's one that should be pretty universal.